# RowMapper invalid column name error in Java

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a query and it works well on the database. However, when I tried to take them as a Java object by using RowMapper, I get an invalid column name error. I checked everything, but I don't understand the reason why this error happening.

My query:

```sql
SELECT TEMP.SUMALLTXN, SUM(TEMP.SUMCARD), SUM(TEMP.SUMERRORTXN), SUM(TEMP.SUMERRORTXNCARD)
FROM
(SELECT
SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS SUMALLTXN,

COUNT(mdmtxn.BIN) OVER (PARTITION BY mdmtxn.BIN) AS SUMCARD,

SUM(case when mdmtxn.MDSTATUS NOT IN ('1','9', '60') then 1 else 0 end) AS SUMERRORTXN,

SUM(case when mdmtxn.MDSTATUS NOT IN ('1','9', '60') then 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY mdmtxn.BIN) AS SUMERRORTXNCARD

FROM MDM59.MDMTRANSACTION2 mdmtxn WHERE
    mdmtxn.CREATEDDATE < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL ':initialMinuteParameterValue' MINUTE ,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AND
    mdmtxn.CREATEDDATE > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL ':intervalMinuteParameterValue' MINUTE ,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')
GROUP BY mdmtxn.MDSTATUS, mdmtxn.BIN
) TEMP
GROUP BY TEMP.SUMALLTXN
```

My RowMapper:

```java
@Component
public class TotalTransactionsReportRw implements RowMapper<TotalTransactionsReportDto> {

    @Override
    public TotalTransactionsReportDto mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return TotalTransactionsReportDto.builder()
                .totalNumbersOfTransactions(rs.getString("SUMALLTXN"))
                .totalNumbersOfCard(rs.getString("SUMCARD"))
                .totalNumbersOfErrorTransactions(rs.getString("SUMERRORTXN"))
                .totalNumbersOfErrorCard(rs.getString("SUMERRORTXNCARD"))
                .build();
    }

    private static class TotalTransactionsDetailRwHolder {
        private static final TotalTransactionsReportRw INSTANCE = new TotalTransactionsReportRw();
    }

    public static TotalTransactionsReportRw getInstance() {
        return TotalTransactionsReportRw.TotalTransactionsDetailRwHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

My Dto:

```java
@Value
@Builder
@Data
public class TotalTransactionsReportDto {
    private String totalNumbersOfTransactions;
    private String totalNumbersOfCard;
    private String totalNumbersOfErrorTransactions;
    private String totalNumbersOfErrorCard;
}
```

And in my tasklet class I created a list to get all data from rowmapper:

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NotificationTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private final PofPostOfficeServiceClient pofPostOfficeServiceClient;
    private final SequenceSysGuid sequenceSysGuid;
    private final BatchProps batchProps;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private String notificationMailSql;
    private String totalTransactionsSql;
    private String endOfHtmlString = "</table></body></html>";
    private String endOfTableString = "</table>";
    private String jobName = "vpos-notification";
    private String tdClose = "</td>";`

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        List<VposNotificationBatchDto> notificationList = getNotificationList();

        List<TotalTransactionsReportDto> totalTransactionsList = getTotalTransactionsList();

        AlertMailDto alertMailDto = createAlertMailDto(notificationList,totalTransactionsList);

        if (!(notificationList.isEmpty())) {
            sendMail(alertMailDto);
        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    List<TotalTransactionsReportDto> getTotalTransactionsList() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                totalTransactionsSql,
                new TotalTransactionsReportRw());
    }

    @Autowired
    public void     setTotalTransactionsSql(@Value("classpath:sql/vposnotification/select_total_transactions_data.sql")
                                               Resource res) {
        int intervalnext = batchProps.getJobProps()
                .get(jobName).getAlertProps().getIntervalMinuteParameterValue();
        String intervalMinutes = String.valueOf(intervalnext);

        int initialMinuteParameterValue = batchProps.getJobProps()
                .get(jobName).getAlertProps().getInitialMinuteParameterValue();
        String initialMinutes = String.valueOf(initialMinuteParameterValue);

        this.totalTransactionsSql = SqlUtils.readSql(res);
             this.totalTransactionsSql = this.totalTransactionsSql.replace(":initialMinuteParameterValue",          initialMinutes);
              this.totalTransactionsSql = this.totalTransactionsSql.replace(":intervalMinuteParameterValue",     intervalMinutes);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
         this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: SUM(X) and X are not the same, so my guess: your problem is here: .totalNumbersOfCard(rs.getString("SUMCARD")) (and the others like it). adjust your query to: SUM(SUMCARD) AS SUMCARD

Comment: Please specify the DBMS you're using. Your query doesn't have columns `SUMCARD`, `SUMERRORTXN` and `SUMERRORTXNCARD`, or at least, not all DBMSes alias `SUM` columns with the name of the column that is summed, so you should alias them explicitly, e.g. `SUM(TEMP.SUMCARD) AS SUMCARD`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry I forget to tell, It is PLSQL

Comment: You mean Oracle?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes it is oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your query doesn't actually have columns `SUMCARD`, `SUMERRORTXN` and `SUMERRORTXNCARD`. Although there are DBMSes that alias `SUM` columns with the name of the column that is summed, Oracle is not one of them. IIRC, Oracle aliases it as, for example, `"SUM(SUMCARD)"` or maybe `"SUM(TEMP.SUMCARD)"`. However, that is an implementation detail you should not rely on in my opinion.

To get the name you want to use, you need to alias your `SUM` columns explicitly, e.g. `SUM(TEMP.SUMCARD) AS SUMCARD`.

Comment: So do you prefer to add alias 'AS' at the first select statement in the query

Comment: @xprop this has nothing to do with preferences. Your mapper goes to look for column SUMCARD in the result of your query, but there isn't such a column, so you need to make sure your column has that name

Comment: Problem has been resolved thank you :)